# Why command + shift + l is changing the order of my views?

Tags: android, android-studio

Every time I do command + shift + L Android Studio is changing the order of the views in a layout.

why is this happening?

It is fine if I use ConstraintLayout but using LinearLayout it change completely the layout.

anyone knows if there has been any change on Android Studio?

Comment: Please check your code style in settings settings>code style> xml .See if there is some additional conditions added

Comment: you are right, I've changed XML style to *Scheme: Project* instead of default and now it does not change the order of the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your code style in settings settings>code style> xml .See if there is some additional conditions added